# unable to change font in fbterm

Tags: arch-linux, fontconfig, fbterm

To change fonts, according to fbterm's [arch linux page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fbterm)

> To change the fonts that are used, use the --font-names option to select favorites from the list given by fc-list.

I listed the fonts

```
fc-list
```

```
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/FiraCode-SemiBold.ttf: Fira Code,Fira Code SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/FiraCode-Retina.ttf: Fira Code,Fira Code Retina:style=Retina,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/FiraCode-Bold.ttf: Fira Code:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/FiraCode-Light.ttf: Fira Code,Fira Code Light:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/FiraCode-Medium.ttf: Fira Code,Fira Code Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/FiraCode-Regular.ttf: Fira Code:style=Regular
```

and started fbterm with the --font-names option

I tried all of these:

```
fbterm --font-names FiraCode
fbterm --font-names FiraCode-Regular
fbterm --font-names FiraCode-Regular.ttf
fbterm --font-names=FiraCode
fbterm --font-names=FiraCode-Regular
fbterm --font-names=FiraCode-Regular.ttf
```

but all resulted in starting with the same font

**How do I change the font in fbterm?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fbterm --font-names="Fira Code"